# Forming the div to the content when the content is curved?

Tags: html, css

I have two list items that I want to be "stacked" next to each other in the y-direction  (but not directly on top of each other in the z-direction) but whenever the content is curved, the div creates whitespace underneath the arc preventing the lower piece from fitting inside.

```css
ul{
    margin: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    
}

li{
    position: relative;
    margin: -7px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Digital Gears</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/project/assets/stylesheets/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = '\\/';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="1">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write(makeid(150));
            </script>
        </li>
        <li id="2">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write(makeid(150));
            </script>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    new CircleType(document.getElementById('1')).radius(384);
    new CircleType(document.getElementById('2')).radius(384);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To be clear, I am trying to figure out how to get the content which is currently spaced like ( ( to fit closer, like ((.

Answer (score 1):

Everything styled on a web page is [basically a box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model), so it makes sense that as long as you're not allowing overlap of the two elements, there will be a gap created by the whitespace of the box. You can solve this problem, by letting the second div overlap the first one slightly. Simply give it a negative margin: `margin-top: -7rem` more or less did it for me.